# Java - absent jar file preventing application from being run

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to make use of the pre-trained model with the code given here https://github.com/uwnlp/EasySRL.

For the basic usage of the code it says one should use

```
    java -jar easysrl.jar --model modelFolder
```

The issue is there does not seem to be a an easysrl.jar anywhere. I'm new to java and am unsure as to how I should proceed. As an attempt I tried to convert one of the folders called easySRL into a jar fie but this failed - I'm not really convinced this was what was intended anyway.

Comment: You need to build the Jar file first, by running the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build tool.

Comment: I agree with @Andreas - if your new this answer I posted might help you out, it was helping another person troubleshoot and they were very new as well [Create a eclipse project using existing ant build xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331437/create-a-eclipse-project-using-existing-ant-build-xml-file/48345004#48345004)