# Java Tutorial/Examples using Google Maps API and dynamic data

Tags: google-maps, jakarta-ee, dynamic

Does anyone know of any tutorials or examples of how to get started in implementing an application using Java EE, Google Maps API and a dynamically tracked object on the Google Maps? An example use would be flight radar/tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Flight Radar?  You'd probably need to scrape some web sites that have semi-real time GPS positions of airline flights.  A RT-SDR dongle tracking ADS-B Radar signal would also work.

As to the Google Maps API, this GitHub Repository would be a good start, it has short examples, build scripts for both Gradle and Maven

[Google maps services Java](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)

If you're using Eclipse and I'm sure NetBeans also has it, my answer (and the questions/comments) on this SO question [Create a eclipse project using existing ant build xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331437/create-a-eclipse-project-using-existing-ant-build-xml-file/48345004#48345004)

Would be a start as to how to get started using Eclipse, build files and J2EE types of projects.  It doesn't refer to Maven and Gradle but you can google around on how to install those plug-ins in Eclipse - then clone the GitRepo linked previously and build it with Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Did this answer help Lauren?